# How did 'man of war' get that name?

Tags: etymology, terminology

In chapter seven of *[Gulliver's Travels](https://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/829)* it is written:

> But hurried on by the precipitancy of youth, and having his imperial majesty’s license to pay my attendance upon the emperor of Blefuscu, I took this opportunity, before the three days were elapsed, to send a letter to my friend the secretary, signifying my resolution of setting out that morning for Blefuscu, pursuant to the leave I had got; and, without waiting for an answer, I went to that side of the island where our fleet lay. I seized a large **man of war**, tied a cable to the prow, and, lifting up the anchors, I stripped myself, put my clothes (together with my coverlet, which I carried under my arm) into the vessel, and, drawing it after me, between wading and swimming arrived at the royal port of Blefuscu, where the people had long expected me: they lent me two guides to direct me to the capital city, which is of the same name.

*Man* here can obviously not mean an actual *[man](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/man#Noun),* but given the context, he seized a [large vessel of war](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/man-of-war).

How did such a vessel get the name ***man** of war*?

Comment: Why do you think it's not [man of war](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/man-of-war) (also often man-of-war, but you can't expect the same punctuation in a 300 year old text)? Or are you asking about the etymology?

Comment: I've made a rather drastic edit to this question because "man of war" has a discrete entry in many dictionaries and is easily found, and the etymology is likely to be less easily found and a more interesting question. The original question asking what a "man of war" was would have been easily and rightly closed.

Comment: That Wikipedia page says "The name [of the creature] *man o' war* comes from the *man-of-war,* a sailing warship," so it doesn't answer the question of why the ship is called that.

Comment: @AndrewLeach — That page does say: *It probably arose in the following manner: 'Men of war' were heavily armed soldiers. A ship full of them would be called a 'man-of-war ship.'*

Comment: For what it's worth, "(God is a ...) *man of war*" is from Exodus, at the Red Sea, an idiom for *soldier*, not that God is the warring type.

Comment: Wiktionary leads to 'Words, facts, and phrases; a dictionary of curious, quaint, & out-of-the-way matters' by Eliezer Edwards, which states that "*It probably arose in the following manner : — 'Men of war ' were heavy armed soldiers. A ship full of them would be called a 'man-of-war ship.' In process of time the word 'ship' was discarded as unnecessary, and there remained the phrase * a man-of-war.'*" ([source](https://archive.org/details/wordsfactsandph00edwagoog/page/350/mode/2up))

Comment: Probably in the sense of *man* meaning servant at the ready (https://www.etymonline.com/word/henchman). A man of war was a ship that belonged to the king. King Henry VII was a major merchant and shipbuilder who loaned and sold ships to other merchants. He seems to have been forced into the protection racket and built a series of man-of-wars to escort and protect his fleet and the fleets of his merchant customers. *Man of War* was a famous ship that carried King Henry VIII to France in 1520 to meet with King Francis I.

Comment: The previous edit has been removed for the reason I mentioned in the edit summary. That the "man" in "man of war" referred to a soldier in a ship, is the meaning and the origin of the noun. Answers should go in the answer box not be edited in questions

Answer (score 5):

The [1908 edition of the OED](https://books.google.com/books?id=NC3WhB-Rd7sC&pg=PA133&dq=%22as+well+for+our+Men+of+war+to+resort%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi-uuWO3qj_AhVYIDQIHTf9CfAQ6AF6BAgHEAI#v=snippet&q=%22Pl.%20Men-of-war%22&f=false) has this entry (unchanged in the 1971 edition of the OED) for *man-of-war*:

> **Man-of-war** *Pl.* **men-of-war** {in sense 1 app[arently] after F. *homme de guerre*; for sense 2, cf. MAN *sb.*<sup>1</sup> 12.} **1.** A fighting man ; a soldier, warrior. *Obs[olete]* exc[ept] *arch[aic]* or *jocular*. ... **2.** A vessel equipped for warfare ; an armed ship belonging to the recognized navy of  country. [Earliest three cited occurrences:] **1484** W. Cely in *C. Papers* (Camden) 144 As he cam to Callez wardd ij [that is, two] men of warre of Frensche mett w<sup>t</sup> hym and fawght w<sup>t</sup> hym. **1594** [*Glenham's Newes fr[om the] Levane Seas*](https://books.google.com/books?id=051TAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA4&dq=%22King+of+Spaynes+men+of+warre%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj2rYui16j_AhWeDjQIHX8jD3kQ6AF6BAgKEAI#v=onepage&q=%22King%20of%20Spaynes%20men%20of%20warre%22&f=false) in Collier *Illustr[ations of] Old Engl[ish]. Lit[erature]* (1866) I.4 In sight of the King of Spaynes men of warre, which were twenty two sayles. **1680** [*Debates in Parl[iamen]t*](https://books.google.com/books?id=-axoiqps3yAC&pg=PA411&dq=%22as+well+for+our+Men+of+war+to+resort%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi-uuWO3qj_AhVYIDQIHTf9CfAQ6AF6BAgIEAI#v=onepage&q=%22as%20well%20for%20our%20Men%20of%20war%20to%20resort%22&f=false) (1681) 120 It {Tangier} will always be Serviceable, as well for our Men of War to resort to..as for the protection of our Merchant-men.

A fairly early instance of "men of warre" in the sense of "ships" (not mentioned by the OED) appears in a 1579 translation of Synesius of Cyrene, [*A paradoxe, prouing by reason and example, that baldnesse is much better than bushie haire, &c.*](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/e/eebo/A13297.0001.001/1:4?ALLSELECTED=1;amt2=40;amt3=40;c=eebo;c=eebo2;g=eebogroup;rgn=div1;singlegenre=All;sort=datea;subview=detail;type=proximity;view=fulltext;xc=1;q1=ship*;op2=near;q2=men*+of+war*):

> Forsomuch therefore as I haue the more excellent cause to defend, notwithstanding my cunning be not counteruaileable vnto Dions, whie should I not make readie my selfe, according to the equitie of my cause, to praise Baldpates, and to dispraise such as are loaden with hairie locks? And for entrance into my matter, I néede no curious or vehement beginning, which I am content to leaue vnto Oratours, as properly pertinent to their earnest cases, wherwith they geue strength to their present purpose, arming it (as it were) against the aduersarie, as the **shippes** (called **men of warre**) are prepared against the enimie.

Another early instance appears in a 1588 translation of Juan González de Mendoza, [*The historie of the great and mightie kingdome of China, and the situation thereof togither with the great riches, huge citties, politike gouernement, and rare inuentions in the same*](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/e/eebo?ALLSELECTED=1;amt2=40;amt3=40;c=eebo;c=eebo2;didno=A01864.0001.001;g=eebogroup;rgn=full+text;singlegenre=All;size=25;sort=datea;start=1;subview=detail;type=proximity;view=reslist;xc=1;q1=ship*;op2=near;q2=men*+of+war*):

> At the end of the two leagues, there whereas the Captaine did leaue the companie of our Spaniardes in the riuer, they came vnto a great baye, whereas was at an anker a fléete of more then a hundreth and fiftie **shippes men of warre**, whose Generall was this Captaine, whom we haue spoken of, that did beare the Fryers and the rest companie.

The relevant portion of the entry for *man*, cited near the beginning of the OED entry for *man-of-war* at the top of this answer, reads as follows:

> **Man** *sb.*<sup>1</sup> ... Transferred uses. ... **14.** With qualification used for : A ship. See also MAN-OF-WAR, INDIAMAN, MERCHANTMAN, etc. [Earliest three cited occurrences:] **1473** J. Paston in *[[The] P[aston] Lett[ers]](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=hvd.hnjr1x&view=page&seq=157&q1=%22Frenchmen%20be%20whyrlyng%22)* III. 81 A few Frenchmen be whyrlyng on the coasts, so that there no fishers go out. **1558** [actually 1578?] W. Towrson [[*The third and last voyage of M. William Towrson to the coast of Guinie, and the Castle de Mina, in the yeere 1577*](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/e/eebo/A02495.0001.001/1:74?ALLSELECTED=1;c=eebo;c=eebo2;g=eebogroup;rgn=div1;singlegenre=All;sort=occur;subview=detail;type=simple;view=fulltext;xc=1;q1=weathermost+man)] in Hakluyt *Voy[ages]* (1589) 125 The *Christopher* being the headmost & the weathermost man, went roome with the Admirall. **1665** *Lond[on] Gaz[ette]* No. 3/4 They chased a Barbadoes and a Jamaica man into Limrick.

It thus appears that *man* as a term for a ship or other vessel comes by simple transference from *man* in the sense of "human being." Just as in common parlance today a game piece can be a man, so in centuries past could a ship. Simple or not, the application of *man* to produce compound names for ships doesn't produce entirely predictable patterns of meaning. For example, the "Frenchmen" in John Paston's March 8, 1473, letter are evidently French navy ships sailing under the French flag; but an *Indiaman* (a word that the OED dates to 1709) is a European ship engaged in trade with India, and a *merchantman* (dating to 1627) is a trading ship operating in service to one or more private merchants.

To cloud the picture somewhat, I note that a number of fairly early accounts included in the Early English Books Online database allude to ships with men of war onboard. For example, from Richard Grafton, [*A chronicle at large and meere history of the affayres of Englande and kinges of the same deduced from the Creation of the vvorlde, vnto the first habitation of thys islande*](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/e/eebo2?ALLSELECTED=1;amt2=40;amt3=40;c=eebo;c=eebo2;didno=A68108.0001.001;g=eebogroup;rgn=full+text;singlegenre=All;size=25;sort=datea;start=1;subview=detail;type=proximity;view=reslist;xc=1;q1=ship*;op2=near;q2=men*+of+war*) (1569):

> And in this tyme also the French king had sent diuers **Ships** vnto the Sea with **men of warre** for to take the English Marchauntes, and other that came in their course.

From Raphael Holinshed, [*The firste [laste] volume of the chronicles of England, Scotlande, and Irelande conteyning the description and chronicles of England, from the first inhabiting vnto the conquest*](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/e/eebo/A03448.0001.001/1:79.1?ALLSELECTED=1;amt2=40;amt3=40;c=eebo;c=eebo2;g=eebogroup;rgn=div2;singlegenre=All;sort=datea;subview=detail;type=proximity;view=fulltext;xc=1;q1=ship*;op2=near;q2=men*+of+war*#hl1) (1577):

> In the latter ende of this eleuenth yeare was the Erle of Arundell sent to the sea with a greate nauie of **ships** and **men of war**.

And from Thomas Chuchyard, [*A generall rehearsall of warres, called Churchyardes choise wherein is fiue hundred seuerall seruices of land and sea as seiges, battailes, skirmiches, and encounters*](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/e/eebo/A18737.0001.001/1:4?ALLSELECTED=1;amt2=40;amt3=40;c=eebo;c=eebo2;g=eebogroup;rgn=div1;singlegenre=All;sort=datea;subview=detail;type=proximity;view=fulltext;xc=1;q1=ship*;op2=near;q2=men*+of+war*) (1579):

> The Turkes vppon the arriuall of the Christians, plucked backe their Batterie, and embarked their greate Ordinaunce, and retired their **men of warre** a **Shipborde**, but in their retire thei loste fifteene hundred Turkes, and those soldiours that were before penned vp issued out, and recouered twoo greate Cannons, *Dom Garsia* was gone backe again to *Saragosa*, for the residue of the Armie.

In these instances, the "men of war" are soldiers, marines, or other fighting men on board ships—so you might argue that "man of war" in the sense of "vessel equipped for warfare" originally arose in the context of instances where a ship was, in fact, loaded to the gills with human "men of war." The OED, however, does not seem to view this origin story as necessary or likely to explain the more general use of *man* as equivalent in meaning to *ship*.

Comment: Regarding the last para - this is because we consider the term to refer to sailing ships with cannon. Prior to Henry VII, men-of-war ships were propelled by oars. The sail on a man-of-war, when present, was mostly to indicate status as carrying somebody in authority.  It was the naval equivalent of the army's unit flag. It was easy to find in the morning after a night at sea. The contemporary sailing ships such as roundboats were used for transporting marines and as merchantmen, not for naval combat.